# How to create a typesafe DSL for interleaved function calls

Tags: f#, dsl

I want to create a DSL where 2 (`foo` and `bar`) functions can be called in succession so that

```
initialize()
|> foo 10
|> bar "A"
|> foo 20
|> bar "B"
|> transform
```

this works pretty perfect by defining

```
type FooResult = FooResult
type BarResult = BarResult

let foo param (result_type:BarResult, result) = (FooResult, transform param result)
let bar param (result_type:FooResult, result) = (BarResult, transform param result)
```

Now however I want to also allow that multiple `bar` calls can be executed in succession however `foo`s still have to be called only once

```
initialize()
|> foo 10
|> bar "A"
//OK
|> bar "B"
|> transform

initialize()
|> foo 10
|> bar "A"
|> foo 20
//should yield an compile error
|> foo 30
|> bar "B"
|> transform
```

In C# I could overload `bar` to either accept BarResult or FooResult but that doesnt work for F#. At least not easily.
I also tried to create some Discriminate Unions but I really cant get my head around it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a fun question!

Your existing code works quite nicely, but I would do one change - you do not actually need to pass around actual `FooResult` and `BarResult` values. You can define a type `MarkedType<'TPhantom, 'TValue>` which represents a value of `'TValue` with a special "mark" specified by the other type:

```
type MarkedValue<'TPhantom, 'TValue> = Value of 'TValue
```

Then you can use interfaces as type parameters for the phantom type. I found it a bit hard to think about the "results", so I'm going to use inputs instead:

```
type IFooInput = interface end
type IBarInput = interface end
```

The trick now is that you can also define an interface that is both `IFooInput` and `IBarInput`:

```
type IFooOrBarInput =
  inherit IFooInput
  inherit IBarInput
```

So, all you need ot do now is to add appropriate annotations to `foo` and `bar`:

```
let foo param (Value v : MarkedValue<#IFooInput, _>) : MarkedValue<IBarInput, _> = 
  Value 0

let bar param (Value v : MarkedValue<#IBarInput, _>) : MarkedValue<IFooOrBarInput, _> = 
  Value 0
```

Here, the annotation on the input says that it should accept anything that is or inherits from `IFooInput` or `IBarInput`. But the result of the `bar` function is marked with `IFooOrBarInput`, which makes it possible to pass it to both `foo` and `bar`:

```
(Value 0 : MarkedValue<IFooInput, _>)
|> foo 10
|> bar "A"
|> bar "A"
|> foo 20
|> bar "B"
```

Comment: wow! I must admit I didn't think in terms of interfaces - but even if I did I certainly wouldnt have come up with such a solution. Do you think a solution with discriminate unions would also be possible?

Comment: I'm not sure DUs would work - the key trick here is to use the inheritance relationship between interfaces (where two different types are compatible). I suppose `inline` and overloading might be an alternative.

Comment: Just one more question. What is the meaning of the hash in `MarkedValue<#IBarInput, _>`?

Comment: The # means anything that is an IBarInput, its the flexible type symbol.

Comment: The "0" of `Value 0` is not used. Can it the definition of `MarkedValue` be changed so "0" is not necessary?